# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string for date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Why can't I create this data

```
INSERT INTO rentails(RENTAILID,DATERENTED, RETURNDATE, CUSTOMERID)
VALUES(105,'2020-28-01','2020-30-01',1);
```

When I created the table I set DATERENTED and "RETURNDATE" to "Date" is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Please, edit your question adding the error you get from the execution of the query

Comment: Perhaps you want `2020-01-28` and `2020-01-30`...

Answer (score 0):

you must specify the format for the date in the query;

```
INSERT INTO rentails(RENTAILID,DATERENTED, RETURNDATE, CUSTOMERID)
VALUES(105,TO_DATE('2020-28-01','YYYY-DD-MM'),TO_DATE('2020-30-01','YYYY-DD-MM'),1);
```